# Deploying two flask applications on apache

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to deploy two applications, app1 on / works as expected.

What's wrong with my virtualhost config? /home/user/flask/app2/app2.py is called but no routes are working (tried '/', '/app2' and the catch all route) giving error 404.

```
WSGIDaemonProcess app1 user=user group=user threads=5 python-home=/home/user/flask/app1/venv
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/app1/app1.wsgi

<Directory /var/www/app1>
    WSGIProcessGroup app1
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    WSGIScriptReloading On
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
 </Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess app2 user=user group=user threads=5 python-home=/home/user/flask/app2/venv
WSGIScriptAlias /app2 /var/www/app2/app2.wsgi process-group=app2 application-group=%{GLOBAL}

<Directory /var/www/app2>
    WSGIProcessGroup app2
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    WSGIScriptReloading On
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
 </Directory>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the order so that the configuration for `/app2` comes first.

This is necessary as they are processed in order and so that for `/` is matching everything and it never gets to `/app2`.

This ordering requirement is discussed in the documentation.

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/configuration-guidelines.html#the-wsgiscriptalias-directive